# bootstrap 3 - Formatting divs and css problems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two problems:

- Divs aren't aligned properly
- How to force thumbnail images to be lined horizontally, and with a horizontal scrollbar (for scrolling) if the thumbnail images exceed the width of the div they're in?

I don't want to use any external js librarys. I am trying to get it to work in pure css and bootstrap 3.

Here is what I have currently so far:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">

            <div class="item">
                   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <div class="main-img">
                                                <img height="500px" width="500px" src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/mt/assets/science/firefox-logo.jpg"/>  
                                        </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                        <div class="row">
                                                <div class="img-list">
                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <img width="100px" height"100px" src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/mt/assets/science/firefox-logo.jpg"/>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <img width="100px" height="100px" src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/mt/assets/science/firefox-logo.jpg"/>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <img width="100px" height="100px" src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/mt/assets/science/firefox-logo.jpg"/>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                                                <img width="100px" height="100px" src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/mt/assets/science/firefox-logo.jpg"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                <span> Title! </span>
                                <span> Some other text!</span>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
     <!-- Some other html here -->
    </div>

</div>
```

I drew an image of what the layout should be:
[image: layout]

The brown area is col-md-10 which contains the following things:

- pink area is the main img (col-md-5)
- dark grey area beneath the pink is the horizontal list of thumbnail images (thumbnails are col-md-3, not sure if that's best?)
- light grey area is just the text descriptions (col-md-7)

I didn't draw the col-md-2 though (which is on the right of the col-md-10 brown area).

Instead, I see a bunch of divs flying all over the place. The thumbnail list is floating at the top right, but the main img and the col-md-7 is correctly side-by-side. The thumbnail list isn't even aligned properly. Can someone help?

Comment: Just checking, you want all the divs to scroll if the image is wider than them?  Most people use the class `.responsive-img` to ensure the image is never more than the width of it's container (`max-width: 100%`). http://jsbin.com/aMufOVu/2/edit

Comment: @davidpauljunior No, I just want to thumbnail list div to have a horizontal scrollbar if there are too many images. Right now I have a few thumbnails, but imagine if that list became 1000 thumbnail images. I don't want the thumbnails to grow smaller when more are added, but rather I'd like them to have a fixed size, but just have a scrollbar so that users can scroll over if they want to view the other thumbnails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go...

http://jsfiddle.net/MUVG5/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">

        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="main-img">
                                <img height="500px" width="500px" class="img-responsive" src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/mt/assets/science/firefox-logo.jpg"/>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="img-list">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <img width="100px" height"100px" class="img-responsive" src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/mt/assets/science/firefox-logo.jpg"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <img width="100px" height="100px" class="img-responsive" src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/mt/assets/science/firefox-logo.jpg"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <img width="100px" height="100px" class="img-responsive" src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/mt/assets/science/firefox-logo.jpg"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <img width="100px" height="100px" class="img-responsive" src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/mt/assets/science/firefox-logo.jpg"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <span> Title! </span>
                    <span> Some other text!</span>
                </div>

            </div>  
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <!-- Some other html here -->
    </div>

</div>
```

If you don't want your thumbs to collapse: http://jsfiddle.net/MUVG5/1/

Comment: Thanks, the collapse one seems like it's the one I want. However, the number of thumbnails are dynamic. It could be 4 like in this example, or it could be 1000+. I would like to keep their size (100px x 100px) for each thumbnail. Right now, I see you've put `col-sm-12`, which fits the four `col-xs-3`. Is there a way to preserve the size of the thumbnail images for 1000+ thumbnail images, but have a horizontal scrollbar to scroll over? Having more than four `col-xs-31` in your example will stack four thumbnail images on top of each other instead of all lined up horizontally.

Comment: When you float items (as Bootstrap columns are) they're taken out of the document flow, and you'll need to know the width of the `.item-list` and set it explicitly along with `overflow-x: auto`.  As you don't know the number of thumbnails you'd need JS.  Otherwise, you can remove Bootstraps float and use display inline-block.  This with a combination of `overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;` on `.item-list` will work but the thumbs won't fit quite as flush. http://jsfiddle.net/MUVG5/3/